# Got ClosedChannelException because writing to channel after it's closed

Tags: java, netty, apache-zookeeper

Our architecture requires that there are two concurrent workflows:

1. writes stuff to netty channel outside netty handler.
2. netty normal life cycles. (connect, close, re-connect..)

We got `ClosedChannelException` and it seems to propogating errors to executors thread pool by looking at stack trace (Netty 3.7).

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureWriteOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:265)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:456)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SocketSendBufferPool$UnpooledSendBuffer.transferTo(SocketSendBufferPool.java:203)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.write0(AbstractNioWorker.java:202)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromTaskLoop(AbstractNioWorker.java:152)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioChannel$WriteTask.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:335)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:366)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:290)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:90)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

My question is:

1. Does it really corrupt the executors thread pool? The case I am worried about: . I would have redesigned the code if I could (bad legacy code). Let me explain more clearly the case I am worried about: some data written to the old closed channel (not actually written yet because of async behavior) -> a new channel is created by reconnection to another address -> the data was actually written to old channel because of async property.
2. How can I handle such concurrency in close and write of netty channel?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'propagating errors to executor's thread pool'? and 'corrupt the executor's thread pool'? A task submitted to the thread pool got an `IOxception`: you logged it; and the write didn't succeed. Something wrong with your application logic here. Worry about that, not the thread pool.

Comment: Hi @EJP. I updated the my concern above. The previous design was for NIO and I am upgrading it to Netty for SSL support. It's not easy to change existing code.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it really corrupt the executors thread pool?

No.

It appears that your code (probably the "writes stuff to netty channel outside netty handler" stuff) has closed the channel to early.  (As @EJP commented, that is a bug in *your* code ...)

This won't corrupt the worker thread, but it *may* have caused the client to have been sent an incomplete response.

> The case I am worried about: some data written to the old closed channel, and a newly created channel (reconnected to another address), will the ClosedChannelException mess things up?

The old closed channel and the new channel will be unrelated.

> How can I handle such concurrency in close and write of netty channel?

Redesign your code so that only the normal Netty "workflow" ever closes the channel.  Making two "workflows" jointly responsible for the closure is a recipe for problems, especially since one of them (the normal Netty workflow) is hard-coded to think that the problem is for it only.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's a big project. You know, it's not easy to change existing workflow...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I would have redesigned the code if I could (bad legacy code). Let me explain more clearly the case I am worried about: some data written to the old closed channel (not actually written yet because of async behavior) -> a new channel is created by reconnection to another address -> the data was actually written to old channel because of async property

Comment: How / why would this "reconnection" happen?  The channels bottom out on sockets, and there is no way to that a socket can be "reconnected" once it has been closed.  Unless they have done something really bizarre and unnecessary ...

Comment: Anyway, the proper fix is to change the code (legacy or otherwise, "big project " or otherwise) so that only Netty closes the channel.  The change is just removing calls to `close()`.  Not a big deal ... unless for some reason you need Netty to NOT `close()` the channel because the other stuff wants to use it afterwards.  (Then you have a big problem ....)

Answer (score -1):

If I'm correct, you get the exception also in your own handler.
I have such exception handling in my handlers since a closed connection could occur for many reasons, at least for instance because the wire is disconnected (so no Netty or application logic fault). The closed normal event could occur "between" you try to submit a write to the channel and the exception.
In my application logic, I take this into consideration, for instance by trying to reconnect, or at least by cleaning the context of the closed connection.

For me, it's not an error but Netty must inform you that there were a temptative made from your application handler to channel that becomes closed.

Comment: The exception is about a closed *channel,* not a closed connection. The application has closed the channel itself and then continued to use it. It is a coding bug.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that a closed exception about a channel occurs ONLY when the application closes itself the channel ? If the channel is closed outside the handler, then the application handler will surely get this exception if it tries to write in between (the closed channel event - not exception - not yet there, but the handler trying to write however). From my point of view, it happens...

Comment: I am 100% sure. If the peer closes the connection, you get -1 from `read()`, `null` from `readLine()`, and `EOFException` from all other `readXXX()` methods. If you're writing you get `IOException: connection reset`. You only get `ClosedChannelException` if you've already closed the channel. See also the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ClosedChannelException.html).

Comment: I don't believe so: as written, `ClosedChannelException` occurs when a write occurs while channel is closed. BUT if the channel is closed somewhere else than the application handler (wire disconnection, remote client closing), then a event `channelClosed()` is sent to the application handler. Again, if in the middle (so the channel is closed but the `channelClosed` event is not received yet) the application handler tries to write, it will possibly get this exception `ClosedChannelException`. That's happening, as I experienced this... my 2 cents...

Comment: No. The *channel* can only be closed by the application. The *connection* can be closed by the peer, which cases `read()` to return -1. Not the same thing.